# How do I translate elementary applications on Weblate?

Tags: translation

Weblate says I do not have permissions to translate. And the pt-br project is without active translators, and it is useless to send suggestions as they will not be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Any users should be able to make suggestions within the elementary weblate instance. If you want to be added to the approved list, you should join the ele-l10n chat https://elementary.io/get-involved#translations